# How to check whether time exists?

Tags: java, datetime

```
frdt = req.getParameter("[FRDT]");


        if(isValidDate(frdt)){
            frdt = req.getParameter("[FRDT]");
        }else{
            frdt = formatDt(frdt);
        }

    private static boolean isValidDate(String input) {
    String formatString = "YYYY-MM-dd";

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString);
       format.setLenient(true);
        format.parse(input);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

My input for frdt (input date) will be 2017-03-27 11:33:21 or only 2017-03-27.
but i have two condition, if only '2017-03-27' without time, it only will run

```
frdt = req.getParameter("[FRDT]");
```

if the date including date and time, it will add 'T' before time.

How to validate the input whethere include time or not?

Please kindly advice.

Thanks and best regards
Sharon

Comment: check the length? If it is longer than 10 you have date with time

Answer (score 0):

You can check if String contains ':' character or else you can split String by space character and if length is greater than 1 then it will indicate that you may have time in input.

Answer (score 0):

I would use regular expression.

```
if (input.matches("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}")) {
    ...
}
```